# What is the difference between versions from a development perspective?

Tags: application-development

Some software (eg veracity, ultraedit) has packages for Ubuntu 10 and another for 11 and another for 12.

What would differences in Ubuntu versions would account for this?

Did the location of files change or something?

Comment: note that there is both an Ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10, 11.04 _and_ 11.10, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Ubuntu versions come with different library versions and different versions of system services. Application software needs to link with this libraries and this linking is version specific. So you need differently linked versions of the same application for different versions of libraries / Ubuntu.